# Indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{\sin(\ln x)}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I have to find the indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{\sin(\ln x)}$ and it seems that it doesn't work with the method used for the integral $\sin(\ln x)$.
Is there anyone who can help me with this? Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is definitely not solvable with elementary means.

Comment: Is there any way of proving that this integral is not solvable? This integral is a part of an exercise for our semester university project.

Comment: Use Risch's algorithm.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2Fsin(ln+x)&assumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22IntegralsWord%22%7D), it is solvable but complex.

Comment: @poetasis The question is whether hypergeometric function is acceptable for presentation of the solution. If the set of functions is unrestricted then any integral is obviously "solvable".

Comment: @we_mor I don't know enough about it to tell you. I just wanted to give you something you could see and perhaps give you ideas for proceeding.